# Need helping debugging this code

Tags: java, debugging

I am trying to figure out how to debug this java program and I keep getting two errors: Cannot find symbol. Would appreciate any help I can get with maybe an explanation as to how you went about fixing it. Thanks!

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class DebugFive1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        final double HIGH_PRICE = 2.59;
        final double MED_PRICE = 1.99;
        final double LOW_PRICE = 0.89;
        String usersChoiceString;
        int usersChoice;
        double bill = 0.0;

        usersChoiceString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Order please\n1 - Burger\n2 - Hotdog\n3 - Grilled cheese\n4 - Fish sandwich");
        usersChoiceString = integer.parseInt(usersChoiceString);
        if(usersChoice == 1 && usersChoice == 2)
            bill = bill + LOW_PRICE;
        else
            bill = bill - MED_PRICE;

        usersChoiceString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Fries with that?\n1 - Yes\n2 - No");
        usersChoiceString = Integer.parse(usersChoiceString);
        if (usersChoice == 1);
            bill = bill + LOW_PRICE;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bill is " + bill);
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler outputs the line number and a little marker showing you exactly where the error occurred. Please include the **full** error text in your question.

Answer (score 4):

This,

```
usersChoiceString = integer.parseInt(usersChoiceString);
```

should be (in both places)

```
usersChoice = Integer.parseInt(usersChoiceString);
```

Note the capital `I` in `Integer`, and that you need to initialize `userChoice`.

Comment: Hello Elliot. I went ahead and changed the lower case i to a capital. Now I am receiving an error: Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to string..

Comment: Integer.parse(usersChoiceString); this method didn't exist in Integer class. May be you are trying to use Integer.parseInt method